# Discord.js V14 Slash Commands do not register globally?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm using discord.js v14 and I'm using this handler to deploy all folders in my commands folder globally except the folder called "dev" with private commands, so all the commands are deployed in the "testing server" but when I invite the bot to another server none of the "global" commands register itself.
here's the command handler code:

```js
const { REST } = require('discord.js');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const commands = [];

// Function to register global commands
const registerGlobalCommands = (commandFolders) => {
  for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands', folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

    for (const file of commandFiles) {
      const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
      const command = require(filePath);

      if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
        commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
      } else {
        console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
      }
    }
  }
};

// Function to register guild commands for a specific guild
const registerGuildCommands = (commandFolder) => {
  const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands', commandFolder);
  const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

  for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);

    if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
      commands.push({
        ...command.data.toJSON(),
        guilds: [guildId] // Set the specific guild ID for guild commands
      });
    } else {
      console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
    }
  }
};

// Grab all the command folders from the commands directory
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(path.join(__dirname, 'commands'));

// Register global commands for utility, fun, and main categories
registerGlobalCommands(commandFolders.filter(folder => folder !== 'dev'));

// Register guild commands for employee category in a specific guild
registerGuildCommands('dev');

// Construct and prepare an instance of the REST module
const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

// Deploy the commands
(async () => {
  try {
    console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application commands.`);

    // Deploy all the commands
    await rest.put(
      '/applications/' + clientId + '/guilds/' + guildId + '/commands',
      { body: commands }
    );

    console.log(`Successfully deployed ${commands.length} application commands.`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to deploy application commands: ${error}`);
  }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can follow tutorial : https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/command-deployment.html#guild-commands

Note this import: `const { REST, Routes } = require('discord.js');`

```js
// Deploy the commands
(async () => {
  try {
    console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application commands.`);

    await rest.put(
       Routes.applicationCommands(clientId),
       { body: commands },
    );

    console.log(`Successfully deployed ${commands.length} application commands.`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to deploy application commands: ${error}`);
  }
})();
```